# How to use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles and have it stop after finding the first match?

Tags: c#, getfiles, file-search

Need to search the directory/sub-directories to find a file, would prefer it to stop once it has found one.

Is this a feature built into DirectoryInfo.GetFiles that I am missing, or should I be using something else (self-implemented recursive search)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles.aspx) instead which is lazily returning the files (as opposed to `GetFiles` which is bringing the full file list into memory first) - you can add `FirstOrDefault()` to achieve what you want:

```
var firstTextFile = new DirectoryInfo(someDirectory).EnumerateFiles("*.txt")
                                                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

From MSDN:

> The EnumerateFiles and GetFiles methods differ as follows: When you
>   use EnumerateFiles, you can start enumerating the collection of
>   FileInfo objects before the whole collection is returned; when you use
>   GetFiles, you must wait for the whole array of FileInfo objects to be
>   returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are
>   working with many files and directories, EnumerateFiles can be more
>   efficient.

(`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` requires .NET 4.0)

Comment: For .NET 3.5 and below, use FindFirstFile() as shown in my example below.

Comment: For recursive search, as topic starter mentioned, just need to use search option to method: EnumerateFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Answer (score 4):

**The best method to use for pre-.NET 4.0, use [FindFirstFile()](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/52-playing-with-findfirstfile-and-findnextfile.html)**

```
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstFile(string lpFileName, out WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FindClose(IntPtr hFindFile);

    public void findFile()
    {
        WIN32_FIND_DATA findData;
        var findHandle = FindFirstFile(@"\\?\" + directory + @"\*", out findData);
        FindClose(findHandle);
    }
```

Requires this struct

```
    //Struct layout required for FindFirstFile
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    struct WIN32_FIND_DATA
    {
        public uint dwFileAttributes;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftCreationTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
        public uint nFileSizeHigh;
        public uint nFileSizeLow;
        public uint dwReserved0;
        public uint dwReserved1;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
        public string cFileName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
        public string cAlternateFileName;
    }
```

Comment: Needed 4.0, but I +1 you as well for a great answer, hoping it will help others with this as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DirectoryInfo.GetFiles([Your Pattern], SearchOption.AllDirectories).First();