# FindFirstFile with IO.Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a situation where I have to find a path to the first file named `my.exe` starting from `startingdirectory` & `\mydir\` and go deep as needed.
Actually, `IO.Directory.GetFiles` is suitable but I need it stop searching after the first file is found like it is possible with `FindFirstFile` from WinAPI.

VB.NET

```
Dim findedDirectories() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles( _
startingdirectory & "\mydir\", "my.exe", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

C#

```
string[] findedDirectories = IO.Directory.GetFiles( _
startingdirectory + "\\mydir\\", "my.exe", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Is it possible to stop searching after the first file is found in a way that the result of the function will be a `string` or an `empty string`, not a `string array`? Or is here better way to search for a first file in subdirectories?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use DirectoryInfo.GetFiles and have it stop after finding the first match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120737/how-to-use-directoryinfo-getfiles-and-have-it-stop-after-finding-the-first-match)

Comment: @AlexFilipovici It's not really a dupe of that since here we are looking for a single file in the directory. A simple call to `File.Exists` is sufficient.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: _...and go deep as needed..._

Comment: @AlexFilipovici OK, I suppose the overload of EnumerateFiles that takes a `SearchOption` parameter does what is required.

Comment: My idea was to not use recursive scanning if DirectoryInfo is sufficient, but it is not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution like the following one could help:

```
/// <summary>
/// Searches for the first file matching to searchPattern in the sepcified path.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="path">The path from where to start the search.</param>
/// <param name="searchPattern">The pattern for which files to search for.</param>
/// <returns>Either the complete path including filename of the first file found
/// or string.Empty if no matching file could be found.</returns>
public static string FindFirstFile(string path, string searchPattern)
{
    string[] files;

    try
    {
        // Exception could occur due to insufficient permission.
        files = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    // If matching files have been found, return the first one.
    if (files.Length > 0)
    {
        return files[0];
    }
    else
    {
        // Otherwise find all directories.
        string[] directories;

        try
        {
            // Exception could occur due to insufficient permission.
            directories = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        // Iterate through each directory and call the method recursivly.
        foreach (string directory in directories)
        {
            string file = FindFirstFile(directory, searchPattern);

            // If we found a file, return it (and break the recursion).
            if (file != string.Empty)
            {
                return file;
            }
        }
    }

    // If no file was found (neither in this directory nor in the child directories)
    // simply return string.Empty.
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the simplest approach would be to organise the recursion into sub-directories yourself with recursive calls to `Directory.GetDirectories` passing `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`. In each directory check for the file's existence with `File.Exists`.

This actually mirrors the way it would be done in Win32 with `FindFirstFile`. When using `FindFirstFile` you always need to implement the sub-directory recursion yourself because `FindFirstFile` has nothing analagous to `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

Comment: Then would be probbably easier (and maybe slower) to filter resulted array 'findedDirectories'?